# How to set a different language to Bot Framework in Facebook Channel?

Tags: c#, botframework, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have registered my bot in Microsoft Bot Framework. When I talk to Bot from the Microsoft page, it asks me confirmation questions in Spanish. Now I add the Facebook channel. When I start a conversation in Facebook Messenger, it asks me confirmation questions in English.

So, How I set a different language to Bot Framework in Facebook Channel in .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET you can set the locale of the activity with

```
  activity.Locale = "es-ES";
```

In the Post method of the controller. (In Controllers/MessagesController.cs for example)

Answer (score -1):

You can configure the bots default locale during construction:

```
 var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, {
        localizerSettings: { 
            defaultLocale: "es" 
        }
    });
```

For confirmation dialogs, you must override them.

[More.](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat/localization/)

Comment: The provided code is JavaScript.The link that you mentioned also show this JavaScript example.